# XSLT boolean of an empty string prints true

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Here is my xslt. Any reason why boolean($x) prints true when boolean($y) prints false when they both have the same value. the only difference is that x gets its empty string by calling a template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="x">
      <xsl:call-template name="tmplate"></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    ###x-bool:[<xsl:value-of select="boolean($x)"/>]
    ###x:[<xsl:value-of select="$x"/>]

    <xsl:variable name="y" select="''"/>
    ###y-bool:[<xsl:value-of select="boolean($y)"/>]
    ###y:[<xsl:value-of select="$y"/>]

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tmplate">
    <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the only difference is that x gets its empty string by calling a
>   template.

No, that's not the only difference.When you define a variable as:

```
<xsl:variable name="y" select="''"/>
```

the data type of the variable is `string`. But when you define it as:

```
<xsl:variable name="x">
    <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

the data type is [result-tree-fragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#dt-result-tree-fragment). It contains a text node that contains an empty string. Therefore it is not empty and will be evaluated as true() when converted to boolean.

Comment: oh ok. I dont know about that. Thank you